# Preceding sibling is not working if there are multiple child tags

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here, to locate checkbox, XPath is written as below.
//td[text()='bbbb vvvvvvvvv']/preceding-sibling::td/div/input[@class='hidden']

But this input is not captured. util "//td[text()='bbbb vvvvvvvvv']/preceding-sibling::td/div/", element is located. Is there any perticulare reason for that?.
I want to know why this XPath is not working?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try webdriverwait and any of follwoing options.

**Option1:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='id' and @type='checkbox']")));
element.click();
```

**Option2:**

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='id' and @type='checkbox']")));
  Actions action=new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

**Option3:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='id' and @type='checkbox']")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you explain why input tag is not located into Xpath in usual way?. Because is that tag not closed?.

Comment: <input > tag is like that only there is no closing like </input> as you thought.